Issue with GCC profiling when executing script: profiling:/build:Cannot create directory
I am setting up an external software package and I am linking it to my code. Compiling my code does not throw any error, but when I am executing the code, the following error is thrown when the code finishes:
profiling:/build:Cannot create directory
profiling:/build/jenkins/workspace/lcg_release_pipeline/build/frameworks/RooUnfold-3.0.0/src/RooUnfold-3.0.0-build/CMakeFiles/RooUnfold.dir/G__RooUnfold.gcda:Skip
profiling:/build:Cannot create directory
profiling:/build/jenkins/workspace/lcg_release_pipeline/build/frameworks/RooUnfold-3.0.0/src/RooUnfold-3.0.0-build/CMakeFiles/RooUnfold.dir/src/TUnfoldV17.gcda:Skip
profiling:/build:Cannot create directory

Does anyone know whats happening here? And does anybody know what I can do to prevent this?

It looks like your are trying to create a directory named /build and others underneath.  It should be no surprise that an unprivileged user cannot do that.  Possibly you meant build (relative to the working directory) instead, or possibly you meant for there to be some leading (relative) directory name, but it's missing (maybe a variable that was supposed to provide it is misspelled or unexpectedly unset).  We can only guess because you haven't provided the code that produces those messages.

I get the identical error message with the same installation of the software (RooUnfold), which is how I found this question!
The error comes from the RooUnfold library having been installed in a different location from where it was built, and the original location not being writeable. I recognise that you are using an LCG ROOT release, which is built under the /build directory, but installed somewhere under the /cvmfs directory. You are picking up the RooUnfold library from there. Unfortunately, I don't know how to fix the LCG release to suppress these messages. They seem to be harmless, just annoying.
If you build the RooUnfold library yourself, you won't get the messages. Maybe you thought you had built RooUnfold, but you are picking up the LCG build instead. That is a problem with your search PATH, which should soon be fixed in this by this update.

Profiling will be disabled by default in a future version of RooUnfold. When that change is incorporated in a new LCG release, these messages will no longer appear.
